# How to perform udp connection to remote server which is connected through VPN?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, vpn

I'm working on simple UDP server development with python on remote server.
Because of the security policy, I have to firstly connect to VPN server and then connect to the remote server with SSH.

But while I can run the `server.py` in the remote server, I cannot receive any packet or message when I run `client.py` in my local PC.

When I tried same codes with other remote PC, I didn't experienced same problems, so I expect the VPN connection must be the matter.

Is there any specific method to connect over VPN?

Examples of my codes are written as below.

> Server:

```
import socket

localIP     = "remote_server_ip"
localPort   = port
bufferSize  = 1024

msgFromServer       = "Hello UDP Client"
bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromServer)

UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))

print("UDP server up and listening")

while(True):
    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)

    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)

    # Sending a reply to client
    UDPServerSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, address)
```

> Client:

```
import socket

msgFromClient       = "Hello UDP Server"
bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromClient)
serverAddressPort   = ("remote_server_ip", port)
bufferSize          = 1024

UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressPort)

msgFromServer = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

msg = "Message from Server {}".format(msgFromServer[0])
print(msg)
```

Comment: Have you tried forwarding the port?

Comment: Is the server running a VPN as well?

Comment: As i know, server is not running VPN. I run a VPN on my local PC and as i type ipconfig, it is shown as PPP Adapter Array Network SSL VPN.

Comment: Okay, that's unusual. Are you running ArrayOs? Is your machine part of a corporate network (used to shield corporate secrets ;) )? This is not a standard VPN set-up. The issue no doubt is NAT or some other sort of firewall, but I don't really know what your set-up is. The problem isn't in the code.

Comment: My OS is standard windows 10 and I'm working on lab. in college. The VPN application is required for the company running remote server. So maybe firewall or blocked port would be the problem? I need to ask to network managers... Thank you for answering!

Comment: Perhaps your VPN blocks UDP

Comment: @swaggg as i tried it in my home, it seems that firewall of my college is not the matter. maybe i need to upload question again in different way..

Comment: @user253751 i would ask it to managers of the company. they are seemingly running secured network.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, that's what a SSL VPN is, from what I understand. It's a type of VPN that corporations often use,  it bypasses the need for using a client, it's often only installed in the browser but in this case is apparently used system-wide. It's a system that's often apparently used on an individual basis, to authorise individual users, making sure only certain employees have access to certain data etc. So assuming the server itself is part of this corporate network (or academic ;) ), running a script there won't work, due to NAT firewall rules.

Comment: @user253751 At least that's my understanding of SSL VPNs, though the concept is new to me.

Comment: So if a firewall is in use, the problem should be the endpoint, not the outgoing connection. The question is where the server.py is located and how it's reached.